# How to fix pd.cut with duplicate edges

Tags: python, pandas

I got an error when I put this code. For the first row `rf['r_quartile']` is passed but for the second one, I got this error.

```
rf['r_quartile'] = pd.qcut(rf['recency'], 4, ['1','2','3','4'])
rf['f_quartile'] = pd.qcut(rf['frequency'], 4, ['1','2','3','4'])
rf.head()
```

Here is an error, how to fix this.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-f4184e0eb655> in <module>()
      1 #Computing Quantile of RFM values
      2 rf['r_quartile'] = pd.qcut(rf['recency'], 4, ['1','2','3','4'])
----> 3 rf['f_quartile'] = pd.qcut(rf['frequency'], 4, ['1','2','3','4'])
      4 rf.head()

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/tile.py in qcut(x, q, labels, retbins, precision, duplicates)
    377         include_lowest=True,
    378         dtype=dtype,
--> 379         duplicates=duplicates,
    380     )
    381 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/tile.py in _bins_to_cuts(x, bins, right, labels, precision, include_lowest, dtype, duplicates, ordered)
    412         if duplicates == "raise":
    413             raise ValueError(
--> 414                 f"Bin edges must be unique: {repr(bins)}.\n"
    415                 f"You can drop duplicate edges by setting the 'duplicates' kwarg"
    416             )

ValueError: Bin edges must be unique: array([  1.,   1.,   2.,   4., 154.]).
You can drop duplicate edges by setting the 'duplicates' kwarg
```

Thnak you.

Comment: After `ValueError`, it suggests `You can drop duplicate edges by setting the 'duplicates' kwarg`. if you read https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html you see that you can do `pd.qcut(..., ..., ..., duplicates='drop')`

Comment: thank you. I decide to drop duplicate but it's got an error

`Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges`

so I don't specifically label and it's work.

`rf['r_quartile'] = pd.qcut(rf['recency'], 4, ['1','2','3','4'])
rf['f_quartile'] = pd.qcut(rf['frequency'], 4, duplicates='drop')`

result going like this `f_quartile = (0.999, 2.0]`

Comment: and what's the new error?