# Using pd.cut with duplicate bins and labels

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using `pd.cut` with the keyword argument `duplicates='drop'`. However, this gives errors when you combine it with the keyword argument `labels`.

The question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70986532/how-to-fix-pd-cut-with-duplicate-edges) question, but that ignores the label part.

Does not work:

`pd.cut(pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), bins=[0, 1, 1, 2])`

Works:

`pd.cut(pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), bins=[0, 1, 1, 2], duplicates='drop')`

Does not work:

`pd.cut(pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), bins=[0, 1, 1, 2], duplicates='drop', labels=[0, 1, 1, 2])`

Wouldn't we expect it to drop the label corresponding to the duplicate entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) documentation is pretty clear, it only concerns the **bins**:

> **duplicates** {default ‘raise’, ‘drop’}, optional
>
> If **bin** edges are not unique, raise ValueError or drop non-uniques.

Also, in any case the labels must be one value less than the bins, so dropping the labels based on the bins would be ambiguous.

This works if you have the correct final number of labels:

```
pd.cut(pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
       bins=[0, 1, 1, 2], labels=['a', 'b'],
       duplicates='drop'
      )
```

Or using a weird programmatic alternative:

```
bins = pd.Series([0, 1, 1, 2])
labels = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'])

pd.cut(pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
       bins=[0, 1, 1, 2],
       labels=labels[~bins.duplicated()[:-1]],
       duplicates='drop'
      )
```

Output:

```
0    NaN
1      a
2      b
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
dtype: category
Categories (2, object): ['a' < 'b']
```